# Always run python 2.6 instead of 3.4 in centos

Tags: python, centos6

I have installed python 3.4 in centos.
So I opened terminal and typed python or idle then always ran python 2.6 not python 3.4.
How can i run python 3.4 instead of 2.6?
thanks you.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with CentOS, but you'll need to set the system environment variables: http://blogs.alliedtechnique.com/2009/04/16/setting-global-environment-variables-in-centos/

Comment: Change the path to python34 instead of python26.

Comment: you can use a shebang line

Comment: Do a `which python` to find out where your current python executable is (or more likely, a link to it) and overwrite it with a link to the version you need. `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python` should probably be enough. But this question is off-topic here as it is only marginally related to programming and is more about general usage of a unix/linux system... Also, this approach will potentially break any system tools written in python2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not replace the default Python!** CentOS's system tools such as yum, system-config-* tools and several other things rely on the default Python 2.6 installation. Set up a [virtual environment](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html) instead, where you can define which is the default version.

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.4 myenviron
source myenviron/bin/activate
```

Comment: This is indeed a good point. Replacing the default Python used by the system will break a lot of things.

Answer (score 1):

First, look for where your Python 3.4 is located:

```
$ which python3.4
/usr/bin/python3.4
```

See if ~/bin (e.g., /home/username/bin) directory is in the PATH environment variable:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/username/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

If not, add the bin directory to PATH, ideally within your ~/.bashrc file. Then create a symlink pointing to the Python interpreter under the bin directory:

```
$ ln -s /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/username/bin/python
```

This way, when you type `python` on the command line, the interpreter specified will be launched.

I am on Debian/Wheezy, so the detail might be slightly different, but a similar approach should work.